# Как заставить mosemove читать все движения мышью?

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть множество элементов, которые при движении мышью должны двигаться. Написал вот такую функцию.

```js
let blur = document.querySelectorAll(".blur");
blur.forEach(function (elem) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let x = e.clientX / window.innerWidth;
    let y = e.clientY / window.innerHeight;
    elem.style.transform = "translate(-" + x * 15 + "px, -" + y * 15 + "px)";
    elem.style.transform = "translate(-" + x * 15 + "px, -" + y * 15 + "px)";
  });
});
```

Но возникла проблема, если двигать мышью очень быстро, то движения мышью не ловятся, отрабатывает только последнее расположение мыши, а надо чтобы работало на все движения мышью. Читал, что это такой принцип работы метода, что он пропускает некоторые движения и фиксирует только последние или типо того, но хотелось бы заставить эту функцию работать как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, если вы достанете из цикла вот это:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let x = e.clientX / window.innerWidth;
    let y = e.clientY / window.innerHeight;
    elem.style.transform = "translate(-" + x * 15 + "px, -" + y * 15 + "px)";
    elem.style.transform = "translate(-" + x * 15 + "px, -" + y * 15 + "px)";
  });
```

то работать будет прекрасно. Я не понял для чего вы вешаете множество раз на window обработчик. Это делается единожды где-то в вашем скрипте, а дальше просто работает как должно.

По идее никаких пропусков быть не должно, по крайней мере в такой реализации я отслеживал вообще все действия пользователя:

```
function idleLogout(object) {
    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
    window.ontouchstart = resetTimer;
    window.onclick = resetTimer;
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', resetTimer, true);

    function abortAutosave() {
        object.clearTimers();
        object.clearCache();
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        // после 10 минут бездействия пользователя сбрасываются таймеры
        t = setTimeout(abortAutosave, 600000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Фишка с пропусками в том, что это не пропуски. Просто положение мыши обновляется раз в N времени, поэтому если шевелить _прям быстро_, часть позиций действительно останется неучтённой. Но это надо действительно разогнаться

Comment: Не думаю, что такое принципиально возможно, потому что я видел скрипты, которые по движению пользователя на канвасе рисовали точки и как не дергай - ничего не пропускало.

Comment: Можно посмотреть вот на такой базовый канвас - http://www.htmlcanvasstudio.com/. Если быстро дергать мышью, то вместо кривых получаются ломаные. Происходит как раз из-за того, что скорость считывания позиции курсора слишком мала для действительно быстрый движений

Comment: Так мне же надо, чтобы 100% времени все эти элементы шевелились при движении мышью, я не знаю как написать так, чтобы это работало без постоянного перебора. Если можете подсказать, буду очень признателен.

Comment: вам надо лишь единажды повесить обработчик на событие onmousemove и он будет работать постоянно. В фрагменте кода, который вы показали вы в цикле навешиваете обработчик несколько раз. Это совершенно ни к чему. Также, как писал комментатор выше - некоторые действия пользователя все-таки могут быть упущены. Я погуглил и узнал, что в браузере есть ограничение на 60 пользовательских действий в секунду, действием считается вообще все что угодно. По этой причине, если дёргать курсором ну очень уж быстро - то какие-то действия будут упущены из-за ограничения браузера.